# characteristic function of $X^n$?

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, characteristic-functions

We have that the random variable $X$ is $N(0,1)$-distributed.
Is there an explicit way of determining the characteristic function of $X^n$

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: What is your motivation for computing the characteristic function of $X^n$?